# Expand multiple for loop embedded inside Perl code

Tags: perl

```
my $limit = 10;
my $new_limit = 20;

$command = '

some_plain_lines_here

foreach my $i (o..$limit-1) { print"
   some loop_lines_here with $i
";}

some_more_plain_lines_here

foreach my $j (0..$new_lmit-1) {print"
   some_more_loop_lines_here with $j
";}

some_more_nonloop_lines_here;
';

#TODO: How to scoop out individual for-loops from command and expand and put replace the result back.
my $out_line = eval $command;
```

I have a piece of code like above where I have a `$command` variable containing a mixture of text and `foreach` loops. The text comes from an XLS and this apparently weird format is to help users write content fast and automate rest in backend.

Now, if there's a single for loop, we can easily call eval and expand the content into an `$out_line`. However in this case we have to scoop out every `foreach` and then replace the expanded output in same location.

I am not sure how to split the content into an array at the foreach boundaries. If we get the array, we can call `eval` as required and expand/stitch back text.

It's essentially a string-to-array conversion problem, but gave the complete picture for clarity.

Comment: Since in principle you can have anything inside those loops (what about an accidental word "foreach"?) this isn't so straightforward.  The core [Text::Balanced](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text::Balanced) is a good tool for parsing nested patterns.  There have been Q-A here, to get you going with the tool.

Comment: Why do you think that you need to have executable code in string eval? That sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: @TLP The idea was to allow users write minimal line in an XLS, so somehow we have to process those lines coming out of cells of XLS. eval seemed to be a good idea. Do you suggest something else...?

And why we are writing code in XLS -> it's part of bigger arrangement, XLS helps to do human readable editing and then we process in backend through Perl script.

Comment: @zdim - thank you, will take a look at this.

Comment: @Ad891 When you eval, you can execute arbitrary code. If you allow someone to enter what they want and then eval it, it can destroy your system. What if someone decides to try and enter `qx(rm -rf /)` and you eval that? Even if the user is not malicious, things can go horribly wrong. Eval should always be a last resort, and 99% of the time, there are better and safer solutions.

Comment: @TLP - Yes, understand the risk. However what is the other option. Users (engineers) need to write those for loops manually and multiple times.

Comment: It is not that difficult to type in a for loop (for and foreach are aliases to the same thing). And even if you cannot handle that, you can always write subroutines. Using eval for that is pointless and dangerous. I would need a practical example of what you need to do to be more specific.

Comment: @TLP - as mentioned yesterday the idea was to have folks write in XLS CELLs. And have that run in backend. If we write directly write in Perl code, then foreach loops are pretty simple to handle. However when you make content of two or more cells interact, the problem was coming.

Anyways that's just user-input style.

That's for taking effort to write the solution code. Got the point. Thinking thru it.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comments, `eval()` is very dangerous and almost always unnecessary. You should basically never use it, except in very controlled and select situations, and certainly never when you do not control what is being eval'ed.

With something like this, you could do the same thing without `eval`. Assuming that the user input is the limits. Note that I am cleaning user input to make sure it is ok to use. You may even insert error feedback to the user, but do not reveal how the de-taint works.

```
use strict;
use warnings;   # always use these

my $limit     = shift;
my $new_limit = shift;       # user input

$limit     //= 10;           # default
$new_limit //= 20;

$limit     =~ s/[^0-9]+//g;  # de-taint input
$new_limit =~ s/[^0-9]+//g;

sub command {
    my ($limit, $new_limit) = @_;
    # some_plain_lines_here <--- dont know what this is supposed to be

    for my $i (0 .. $limit-1) { 
        print "some loop_lines_here with $i";
    }

    # some_more_plain_lines_here

    for my $j (0 .. $new_lmit-1) {
        print "some_more_loop_lines_here with $j";
    }

    # some_more_nonloop_lines_here;
}

#TODO: How to scoop out individual for-loops from command and expand and put replace the result back.
# ^-- no idea what this means

command($limit, $new_limit);     # execute the command
```

It is impossible to say what you could put in a subroutine like this without knowing more about what you are looking for. But you sure do not need `eval()` to perform a for loop and print.